# How to fetch in parallel between components?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 3, when using fetch to get data for a page which should be used in a component, what is the right way to wait for it in the component?

**app.vue**

```
<templage>
  <Sidebar/>
  <NuxtPage>
</template
```

**page.vue**

```
const paramsStore = useParamsStore();
const {category} = storeToRefs(paramsStore);

const {data: product} = await useFetch('/api/product', {
  params: { ... }
});
category.value = product.value.category;
```

**Sidebar.vue**

```
const paramsStore = useParamsStore();
const {category} = storeToRefs(paramsStore);

const {data: sidebar} = await useFetch('/api/sidebar', {
  params: { 
    category: category.value    // <<< need to wait for the product fetch to finish
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add pendding to your code. While it is on getting data from server the pending is true and it shows a spinner for example.

```
<div v-show="pending">
/// a spiner tag comes here
```

and in your script setup

```
const {pending, data: sidebar} = await useFetch('/api/sidebar', .....
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **app.vue:**

   - This is the main component template where we include the `Sidebar` component and the main content, which is rendered by `NuxtPage`.

```html
<template>
  <Sidebar :sidebarData="sidebarData" />
  <NuxtPage />
</template>
```

2. **page.vue:**

   - In this component, we use the `asyncData` function provided by Nuxt 3 to fetch product data from the server using `useFetch`.
   - We return the product category as a reactive reference.

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useFetch } from 'nuxt-composition-api';

export default {
  async asyncData({ params }) {
    const { data: product } = await useFetch('/api/product', {
      params: { /* ... */ }
    });

    return { category: ref(product.value.category) };
  }
};
```

3. **Sidebar.vue:**

   - This component receives the `sidebarData` prop, which will be updated based on the selected category.
   - We use the `useFetch` function to fetch sidebar data based on the current category. The fetched data is then assigned to the `sidebarData` prop.

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ sidebarData }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { useFetch } from 'nuxt-composition-api';
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';

export default {
  props: {
    sidebarData: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },

  setup(props, { root }) {
    const category = ref(root.$data.category);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data: sidebarData } = await useFetch('/api/sidebar', {
        params: { category: category.value }
      });

      props.sidebarData = sidebarData;
    };

    watch(category, fetchData, { immediate: true });

    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

So see,  the product category is fetched in the `page.vue` component using `asyncData`, and this category is then passed to the `Sidebar.vue` component as a prop. In `Sidebar.vue`, the component watches for changes in the category and fetches the corresponding sidebar data, updating the `sidebarData` prop accordingly.

I hope this it will help you I search for references and this is the solution I was able to come up with.

Thank you.